# Webpack + React and Google Chrome 43.0.2357.65

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, reactjs, webpack

After updating Google Chrome (v. >= 43.0.2357.65) error was displayed in console: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token function` in different places of my bundle.js.

It appears only when bundle.js returns 200 http status. But after refresh page this file returns 304 http status and all works fine without errors. I'm using webpack v.1.8.5 and React v.0.13.2

**In other browsers code works fine, and in Google Chrome before update it works fine.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this [Chrome issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=489944) and this related [Twitter conversation](https://twitter.com/yaypie/status/600738702038409216) from the person who filed it.

If you're using an older version of Node.js in your build, updating it might fix this. From the issue:

> broken.js was the result of a build script running in Node.js 0.10.18, which seems to have written the file with some peculiar character encoding issues